# Bilinear diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there a fast way ($O((\log n)^c)$) to solve
$$ax+by+xy=n$$ over integers when $a,b$ are known and $0<x,y<a,b$ holds?

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1968-0224543-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (x+b)(y+a) = n + ab  $$
four

Comment: stupid me....... so equivalent to factoring? ok.

Comment: if I said $0<x^2,y^2<a,b$ would it change?

Comment: @student, I don't see how bounds would change much unless they would immediately rule out all, or almost all, solutions. If $n+ab$ is prime then $x+b = \pm 1, \pm n,$ similar for $y+a.$ On the whole, problems filled with variables do not allow you to predictably take advantage of special features.

Comment: @WillJagy I do not get the "four" part. Can you enlight me a bit?

Comment: @mvw i said I could not post the answer because i had four too few characters. Then I forgot about it.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks!